# Block editing disappeared

Tags: 7, blocks

Until last week, when i logged in as administrator, on the page of nodes,
i could edit blocks by clicking "edit this block" link which appeared in upper right corner of blocks.
But now i can't see edit block link, so for every time i want to edit block i go to "/admin/structure/block" which is very bad.

When i check the page source i can see the links like:

```
<div class="contextual-links-wrapper">
<ul class="contextual-links element-hidden">
<li class="block-configure first last">   
<a href="/admin/structure/block/manage/block/32/configure?  
destination=admin/config/development/performance">Edit block</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

What would be the problem.
How can i solve this?
Can you please help me.

Comment: Did you change your theme ? Is the Contextual Links module still enabled ?

Comment: @Countzero thank you for your interest. I didn't change the theme.            "Contextual Links" is enabled. After your message I disabled it, run a cron then enabled module again, but the result is the same.   I can see "contextual-links-wrapper" div class in my nodes' source files. But they are not seen in browser window..

Comment: You mean : the code is in the template but you doesn't make it to the HTML source in the browser ? If true then something's wrong with the template file which is picked up.

Comment: I didn't check the template files. I can see contextual links in HTML source of page. But i can't see them when i hover on the block.

Comment: Then you probably have a js error somewhere.

Comment: @Countzero Thank you very very much. After clearing "sites/default/files/js" folder everything became fine again. I understood that in "/admin/config/development/performance" page, if i select "aggregate javascript files" then contextual links became invisible. If i close aggregating javascript files, everything works fine.     Is it not possible to aggregate js files and see contextual links?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the Theme Developer module enabled? I had the same problem (disappearing contextual links menu for blocks) and disabling the Theme Developer module resolved the issue. Likely something to do with the z-order being utilized by Theme Developer.